# A function that prints out tables from 1 to 10 using iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, iteration

```
def tablesOneToTen():  # a function that will print out multiplication tables from 1-10
    x = 1
    y = 1
    while x <= 10 and y <= 12:
        f = x * y             
        print(f)
        y = y + 1
    x = x + 1

tablesOneToTen()
```

I am trying to make a function that will give me values from the multiplication table from `1-10`.

Should I add `if` and `elif` statements in addition to nested `while` loops to make this code work?

Comment: Start by getting your indentation straight: `x` never changes inside the `while` loop, at least as the code has been posted.

Comment: You need two loops. `x` needs to keep starting from `1` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these sort of iteration tasks you're better off using the `for` loop since you already know *the boundaries* you're working with, also Python makes creating `for` loops especially easy.

With `while` loops you have to check that you are in range using conditionals while also explicitly incrementing your counters making mistakes all the more likely.

Since you know you need multiplication tables for values of `x` and `y` ranging from `1-10` you can, to get you familiar with loops, create two `for` loops:

```
def tablesOneToTen():  # a function that will print out multiplication tables from 1-10
    # This will iterate with values for x in the range [1-10]
    for x in range(1, 11):
        # Print the value of x for reference
        print("Table for {} * (1 - 10)".format(x))
        # iterate for values of y in a range [1-10]
        for y in range(1, 11):                
            # Print the result of the multiplication
            print(x * y, end=" ")            
        # Print a new Line.
        print()
```

Running this will give you the tables you need:

```
Table for 1 * (1 - 10)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
Table for 2 * (1 - 10)
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
Table for 3 * (1 - 10)
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
```

---

With a `while` loop, the logic is similar but of course just more verbose than it need to since you must initialize, evaluate the condition and increment.

As a testament to its uglyness, the `while` loop would look something like this:

```
def tablesOneToTen():
    # initialize x counter
    x = 1

    # first condition
    while x <= 10:
        # print reference message
        print("Table for {} * [1-10]".format(x))
        # initialize y counter
        y = 1
        # second condition
        while y <=10:
            # print values
            print(x*y, end=" ")
            # increment y
            y += 1
        # print a new line
        print(" ")
        # increment x
        x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Python 3`

```
for i in range(1, 10+1):
    for j in range(i, (i*10)+1):
        if (j % i == 0):
            print(j, end="\t")
    print()
```

or:

```
for i in range(1, 10+1):
    for j in range(i, (i*10)+1, i):
            print(j, end="\t")
    print()
```

Output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20  
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30  
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Hope it would help you to get 1 to 10 table.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in a:
    print(*("{:3}" .format (i*col) for col in a))
    print()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.